# Gradle 401 unauthorized when setting credentials from jenkins

Tags: gradle, jenkins

I am passing credentials from jenkins for gradle build:

```
 ./gradlew -DNEXUS_PASSWORD=**** -DNEXUS_USER=nx-test-user test build publish
```

In gradle file, am using this code block:

```
repositories {
            maven {
               
                credentials {
                    username = System.getProperty("NEXUS_USER") 
                    password = System.getProperty("NEXUS_PASSWORD")
                }
                  url = "https://my-url/content/repositories/snapshots/"
                
                 authentication {
                    basic(BasicAuthentication)
                }
            }
        }

......

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    println System.getProperty("NEXUS_USER") ? System.getProperty("NEXUS_USER") : 'no user'
}
```

In test block, i can see the value for the user.
But during the build,"Task: compileJava" when trying to download the images, it says 401 unauthorized.

Where is the problem? Removing authentication block does not help.